# Multivariate analogue of Jackson's inequality's modulus of continuity form

Tags: harmonic-analysis, approximation-theory

According to [Jackson's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson%27s_inequality), there is $c > 0$ s.t. for any continuous function $f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (where $S^1 := \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ is the circle) and integer $n$ there is a trigonometric polynomial $q: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of degree $n$ s.t.

$$\lVert f - q \rVert_\infty \leq c \, \omega(f,\frac{1}{n})$$

Here $\omega$ is the modulus of continuity:

$$\omega(f,\delta):=\sup_{\substack{x \in S^1 \\ h \in [0,\delta]}} \lvert f(x) - f(x + h) \rvert$$

I'm looking for a generalization of this theorem to functions $f: T^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $T^d := \mathbb{R}^d / \mathbb{Z}^d$ is the canonical $d$-dimensional torus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cartwright and Kucharski](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904588901025) give a generalization of Jackson's inequality for an arbitrary compact connected Lie group. I only need the uniform norm, rank 1 case for the canonical torus, so I state here this special case.

## Theorem

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then there is $M_n >0$ s.t. for any $r > 0$ there is $K_r \in C^\infty(T^n, \mathbb{R})$ s.t. its Fourier transform satisfies $\operatorname{supp} \hat{K}_r \subseteq \{\vartheta \in \mathbb{Z}^n \mid \lVert \vartheta \rVert \leq r\}$ and for any $f \in C(T^n, \mathbb{C})$ we have

$$\lVert f - K_r * f \rVert_\infty \leq M_n \sup_{d(z,w) \leq \frac{1}{r}} \lvert f(z) - f(w) \rvert$$

Comment: I'm looking for a quantitative version of this results. (Explicit value for the constant $M_n$.) Is there such a result?